# Do I need "that" in the following sentence?

Tags: ellipsis, conjunctions

> She glanced around nervously, apparently worrying (that) the customers would
>   overhear.

Someone told me that you can omit "that" when using [reporting verbs](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1255&bih=866&q=reporting%20verbs&oq=reporting%20verbs&gs_l=serp.12..0l10.81735.81735.0.81981.1.1.0.0.0.0.140.140.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.139.N8DKsdgxfMA):

> I realized (that) she was a good person.

I'm not very sure about my first example, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence the "***that***" can be omitted, but it becomes somewhat *awkward* because the absence of any word between them brings "**worrying**" and "**customers**" so close together that a reader gets a wrong impression of "*her*" "*apparently worrying customers*".  Because of that I would keep "*that*" there.

In the second sentence the "***that***" can be omitted without such an ill effect, so use it or drop it, the meaning is the same.